# C# Find Specific Node in Binary Search Tree

Tags: c#, search, binary-search-tree, nodes

been noodling around with BST's and I have a pretty good idea of them but I would like to be able to search for a particular node in the BST and have it tell me if it exists. I am using strings in the BST and everything seems to work well but I cannot figure out this Find method. If someone could tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix it this would be appreciated.

```
class Node
    {          
        public string number;
        public string data;
        public Node left;
        public Node right;
        public string Content;
        public Node(string data)
        {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }
    class BinarySearchTree
    { 
        public Node root, current;
        public BinarySearchTree()
        {
            this.root = null;
        }

        public void AddNode(string a) // code to insert nodes to the binary search tree
        {
            Node newNode = new Node(a); //create a new node
            if (root == null) // if the tree is empty new node will be the root node
                root = newNode;
            else
            {
                Node previous;
                current = root;

                while (current != null)
                {
                    previous = current;

                    if (a.CompareTo(current.data) < 1) //if the new node is less than the            current node
                    {
                        current = current.left;
                        if (current == null)
                            previous.left = newNode;
                    }                         
                    else //if the new node is greater than the current node
                    {
                        current = current.right;

                        if (current == null)
                            previous.right = newNode;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public string FindNode(Node node, string s)
        {
            if (root == null)
                return Output = "not found";
            else if (s.CompareTo(root.data) < 1)
                return FindNode(root.left, s);
            else if (s.CompareTo(root.data) > 1)
                return FindNode(root.right, s);

            return Output = "found";
        }

        string SearchResult = "";
        static string Output = "";
        public string Display(Node rootNode)
        {
            if (rootNode != null)
            {
                Display(rootNode.left);
                Output += rootNode.data;
                Display(rootNode.right);
            }
            return Output;
        }           
    }

    private void btnExecute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BinarySearchTree btree = new BinarySearchTree();
        btree.AddNode("D");
        btree.AddNode("B");
        btree.AddNode("F");
        btree.AddNode("E");
        btree.AddNode("A");
        btree.AddNode("G");
        btree.AddNode("C");
        string target;
        txtOutput.Text += "The sorted values of the Binary Search Tree are: \r\n \r\n";
        txtOutput.Text += btree.Display(btree.root);
        txtOutput.Text += btree.FindNode(btree.root, "A");

    }
```

Comment: You know, debuggers make life much easier. That said, FindNode() should have node.left, instead of root.left. Same for right. Also your AddNode fails for insertion of existing nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the following:
1. Use `CompareTo` method with 0 not 1, so `a.CompareTo(current.data) < 1` should be `a.CompareTo(current.data) < 0`
See documentation [IComparable.CompareTo Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
2. As your `FindNode` is recursive call, change `root` to `node` usage

```
public string FindNode(Node node, string s)
{
    if (node == null)
        return Output = "not found";
    else if (s.CompareTo(node.data) < 0)
        return FindNode(node.left, s);
    else if (s.CompareTo(node.data) > 0)
        return FindNode(node.right, s);

    return Output = "found";
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: This was perfect, found my solution. Thanks